# several UDP sockets, bound to same port?

Tags: network-programming, udp

first - it's not a question of "how to bind to port of another software".

now, i have a client-server app, based on TCP and i'd like to make it UDP, but i'm missing something..

i have 2 rules (which i put) to this app:
1) the "server" can stay behind router without any port forwarding configuration.
2) the "client" can listen to only one port.

in TCP i do it like this:
1) the server opens initial connection to the client on port X.
2) when the client wants to open communication channel to the server it uses the initial socket to ask the server for a new one.
3) the server creates a new socket and connect to the client on port X.
4) the client accept this new connection on port X, and now the client talk with the server on this new socket.

this way i can have multiple connections on the same port.

in UDP, i have a little problem..
1) the server sends the initial connection dgram to the client on port X.
2) when the client wants to open communication channel to the server it sends request for a new socket to the initial socket's addr.
3) the server receives the message, creates a new udp socket, and use it to send data to the client on port X.
4) the client receives the new dgram, and ....?

basically what i want to happen now is to "accept" this connection. meaning: to create a new UDP socket, to bind it also to port X and receive data only from that specific incoming socket addr (ip,port). but i cannot do that because i can't bind multiple socket to same port.
so what is the way to create multiple udp connections on one port? (in networking way, not just create a ring buffer of dgrams and send to the right socket)

thanks :)

Comment: You can't have "connection" with UDP because UDP is not a "connected" protocol but datagram protocol.

Comment: and i did was very careful not to say the "connection" word in the UDP matter. when i say "connection" i mean to open a gate for answering..
so what i want is just the server side (which is blocked from outside) to sends a UDP dgram to the client, so the client could later on send dgram to that socket, and receive dgrams from only that specific socket (like tcp accept)

it was possible, if i could bind a new socket on the same port, and receive data only from the (ip,port) that i want.

Comment: @sfk Despite UDP being stateless protocol, connect() call does influence socket operations in a major way. For instance, on FreeBSD, you can't get errors (like ICMP destination unreachable) from UDP socket unless it's connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As UDP is connectionless protocol, on step 4 you check the contents of UDP message and decide how to handle it. In other words, the type of message is defined only by it's contents.

However, I have a feeling that your whole design is a bit wrong. It's much more common for the *client* to be behind firewall (just because there exist more clients, than servers). If you need to put the server behind firewall, you just configure the firewall to allow connections to the set of ports. Even when you have just one more port opened, nothing prevents the client from connecting to the same server port several times in parallel.

Comment: well, this solution means just to change the design of the software and the protocol so that in each dgrarm there'll be a header which says what should i do with it.
i'm searching for something that won't change the design so i could switch easily between TCP and UDP modes.

about the server-client thing.. the "server" is a mobile phone.. so i don't have valid ip.

Comment: @RoeeK yes it does, cause your current "design" is far from optimal.

Comment: i can't think of a better way to create a server-client communication where the server has no valid ip address. thats why it's so strange.. because in order the client can talk with the server, the server needs to open a socket to the client side.. which makes the client side a server.. so i just put the most clear terminology that i could.. but actually both sides are client and servers

Comment: @RooeK I think you need to change client and server terms, then think again and find out that the task has been solved lots of times before. Your "client" is a server, and what it does is similar to FTP server in Passive mode, where the server tells the client, on which port data connection must be established.

Comment: correct, the only problem is my limit: the client side can listen to only one port.

in tcp it's enough.. i understand that in UDP it's not so imposible?

Comment: @RoeeK Established TCP connection is defined by 4 "attributes" -- server address, server port, client address and client port. This is why it's enough - this combination is always unique. In UDP you have a "mailbox" on certain address and port. You receive messages sent to it, and then you can dispatch them based on their contents and on information what IP address sent those messages. But IP address is not unique (you can have multiple senders on the same computer), so if you use a single address and port for a "mailbox", you must dispatch messages based on their contents.