# Nodejs - UDP how to detect already bound ports

Tags: node.js, udp

In Node.js, when I try to bind two UDP socket onto the same port, I don't get any errors, but the last server is the only one to receive the datagrams.

Is there a way to prevent this kind of collision ?
Can I detect which port are already taken ?

Comment: Simple hack would be to store the ports in a hash, but I am unaware of any ways to check which ports are taken (there very well might be). You should should check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638715/several-udp-sockets-bound-to-same-port

Comment: Well, I meant not in the same node instance ... so the hash hack wouldn't work.

Comment: How about using redis?

Comment: Can you force `SO_REUSEADDR=false`?  It would appear a flawed setup.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be impossible to detect bounded ports, except by sending and waiting for an answer.